# How can i change frame widget width in python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, width, frame

I'm trying to resize a frame in tkinter, but the width does not change and function winfo_width() returns 1. How can i fix it?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Test", width = 200)
Frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label = Label(Frame, text = '').grid(row = 0, column=0)


print(Frame.winfo_width()) #output is 1 instead of 200

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you want to add `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` to your code. This will tell row/column 0 to expand evenly. Then add `sticky='nsew'` to your `grid()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have pointed out how to set a static size frame using `grid_propagate()` I will show you how to set up your frame to resize automatically.

You need to tell the row and column to expand that the frame is in. This is done with `columnconfigure()` and `rowconfigure()`. Then you need to tell the frame to stick to all sides with `sticky='nsew'`. Adding widgets to the frame is no different then any other container. Simply tell the widget to be in the frame.

One potention issue I see is you are overwriting `Frame()` on this line: `Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Test", width = 200)`. This is a good example why you should not use import `*`. Instead do `import tkinter as tk` and use the `tk.` prefix for anything that needs it.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Test', width=200)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
label = tk.Label(frame, text='label').grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Update:

If you do want something static make sure you define both height and width. If you only define one or the other then you will not see the frame in the window.

For a testable example for a static frame size:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Test', height=200, width=200)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.grid_propagate(False)
label = tk.Label(frame, text='label').grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The width is returning 1 because the window hasn't been drawn yet. The actual width depends on the window being drawn since the actual width depends on many factors which can't be known before the window is actually drawn.

If you call `root.update()` before calling `Frame.winfo_width()` to force the window to be drawn, you will see it displaying the actual value.

As for how to change the width, that question is too broad to answer. Normally it's not wise to directly set the width of a frame. Tkinter by default will automaticaly resize a frame to fit its children. So, one way to make the frame wider is to add more widgets.

The width can also depend on how it is added to the display - whether you're using `pack` or `grid` or `place`, and how you have configured them. So, another way to make the frame wider is to use non-default options that cause the frame to grow or shrink to fit the space given to it.

If you want to specify an explicit size and ignore tkinter's automatic resizing, you can do that by turning off *geometry propagation* and then setting the `width` and `height` parameters for the frame. Depending on whether you're using `grid` or `pack`, you can call `grid_propagate` or `pack_propagate` with a `False` argument to disable propagation (`place` doesn't support geometry propagation).

Note that turning off geometry propagation is usually the least desirable solution because it requires you to do a lot more work to create a responsive UI. The best way to design GUI with tkinter is to focus on the size of the inner widgets and let tkinter compute the most efficient size for frames and the window itself.

Comment: I would like to add that if you are using `grid_propagate` you will need to specify height and width. Just specifying width appear to leave the screen blank or maybe the frame is just a zero height at that point. It looks like this happens on both grid and pack propagate.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: yes, if you turn off propagation you are fully responsible for the size.

Comment: I thought it would be good to mention as the OP only specifies width. They may be confused when their frame doesn't show up after using grid_propagate.

Answer (score 1):

Your frame can propagate on the grid based on the widgets on it, and not have fixed dimensions.

The output of `1` is due there being nothing on the Frame other than an empty Label. (It would still show `1` if there was no Label)

To get the output as `200`, set the `grid_propagate` flag to False (**only** after setting your height and widht parameters), as follows:

```
frame = Frame(..., width=200)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.grid_propagate(False)
```

Comment: After i use frame.grid_propagate(False) i can't add any widgets to the frame.

Comment: @Artem that is highly unlikely. grid propagate has nothing to do with adding widgets.

Comment: @Mike-SMT so how can i resize the frame **and** add widgets there?

Comment: _"The output of 1 is due there being nothing on the Frame other than an empty Label."_ is not a true statement. It is 1 because the frame hasn't been drawn yet. Since it has a child, it's actual size will be greater than one, and is dependent on the font used when the window is drawn.